# Question out of Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I need to change $\omega = dx \wedge dy$ to polar coordinate. I have

\begin{align}
\omega &= dx \wedge dy\\
&=d(r \cos \theta)\wedge d(r \sin \theta)\\
&=(\cos \theta d r-r \sin \theta d \theta)\wedge (\sin \theta dr + r \cos \theta d \theta)\\
&=\cos \theta \sin \theta \, dr \wedge dr+r \cos^2 \theta\, dr \wedge d \theta-r \sin^2 \theta d \theta \wedge dr - r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \, d \theta \wedge d \theta\\
&=r \cos^2 \theta\, dr \wedge d \theta + r \sin^2 \theta \, dr \wedge d \theta\\
&= r(\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 \theta)\, dr \wedge d \theta\\
&= r \, dr \wedge d \theta
\end{align}

Is what I have written down the correct manipulation of $\omega$? Here, the $5$th equality holds since $dr \wedge dr = 0$ and as $(dr \wedge d \theta)=-(d \theta \wedge dr)$. Basically wanna know if I am computing the differential forms correctly using the wedge product. This is Exercise $14.19$ of page $361$ out of John M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Comment: This is completely correct, and explains the polar coordinates formula that you use in Multivariable Calculus to calculate integrals of functions of regions in the plane: 
$$
dA = dx \, dy = r \, dr \, d\theta
$$

Comment: Thanks! and yeah, I noticed, so cool!! @SammyBlack

Comment: Notation: with differential forms (whether inside an integral or not), it's nice to put a bit of space between the function and the form itself (LaTeX does not by default). You can code it like this: `r \, dr \wedge d\theta` to produce $r \, dr \wedge d\theta$

Comment: Thanks for that!!! @SammyBlack I was wondering how to get that space Lee has in his text!